# Intellij IDEA SCSS support

Tags: intellij-idea, sass

Does Intellij Idea support SCSS? I have Intellij Idea 11.1 and it doesn't. How can I fix it (I'm not Ruby developer)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have **SASS support** bundled plug-in enabled in `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Plugins`.

Note that this feature is only available in IntelliJ Ultimate.

Comment: Notice that this does not provide automatic compilation of SCSS to CSS (at least in idea 12). However, there is a plugin in idea 12 (filewatcher if i am not wrong) that can help you with this... if someone is interested how, let me know.

Comment: [File Watchers feature](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/03/file-watchers-in-webstormphpstorm-6-a-k-a-background-tasks/) was added in IDEA 12.1.

Comment: I can't find this plugin. Is it only available for IntelliJ Ultimate?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari yes, this feature is Ultimate specific: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html.